# Cannot Show a New Form (aboutBox) in C#

Tags: c#

IDE/Language: Visual Studio 2010 Professional C#

I am banging my head against the wall on this one. I have my application nearly finished but I am running into a silly problem. I cannot launch my about box when my About Box menu item is clicked. It either shows nothing or creates a new form.

I have tried several suggestions found on Stack Overflow below however none of them launch my aboutBox class. (Note: I tried these separately and not all at once):

Snippet from mainWindow.cs:

```
 private void aboutMyProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new aboutBox()); //throws and exception

        (new aboutBox()).ShowDialog(); //creates a new form does not run the one I created

        aboutBox about = new aboutBox(); 
        about.ShowDialog(); //creates a new form does not run the one I created
    }
```

This is what is in aboutBox.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class aboutBox : Form
    {
        public void aboutBoxMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = String.Format("About {0}", AssemblyTitle);
            this.labelProductName.Text = AssemblyProduct;
            this.labelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}", AssemblyVersion);
            this.labelCopyright.Text = AssemblyCopyright;
            this.textBoxDescription.Text = AssemblyDescription;
        }
    #region "Assembly Accessors"
    ...
    #endregion
    #region "On-click Events"
    ...
    #endregion
    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Shouldn't `aboutBoxMain()` be `aboutBox()`?

Comment: When you say: "creates a new form does not run the one I created" - what exactly do you mean? Which form *does* it show?

Comment: What does it run when you say it creates a new form but not the one you created? What form is it running them?

Comment: @minitech if I change `aboutBoxMain()` to `aboutBox()` I receive a error "The name conflicts with the name of the enclosing type. If you continue, the changes will not be verified." and it will not compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet and DeCaf I cannot identify the window. It is just a new blank form with not title and the default icon.

Comment: Hans's answer below will fix your problem, see my comments to show why you are having a problem.

Comment: @MystereMan thank you for clarifying the issue with `void` I learned something new today. I also would like to thank everyone else who commented. Solved, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public void aboutBoxMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // etc..
    }
```

You destroyed the constructor somehow, possibly after renaming the form and trying to get rid of the compiler error.  Fix:

```
    public aboutBox() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: To be specific, the constructor should not return a void.  A constructor has no return value, and it has to be named the same as the class itself.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had to delete `void` before renaming the method to `aboutBox()`